# Conditionally sort a single column in ascending and descending order in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby

I have 98,000 USA home street addresses that I need to sort in 'walking' order, i.e. listed in the order that you would walk, down one side of the street and then cross the street and walk back.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('c:pdsort.xlsx')

# add boolean column for even or odd on number column
is_even = df.loc[:,'number'] % 2 == 0
df.loc[:, 'even'] = is_even

# group and then sort by number
df.groupby(['town','street','even']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('number'))

# sort odd numbers ascending and even numbers descending
```

Desired df results, sort ascending for odd street numbers, then switch to descending sort for even. [sorry, first stackoverflow question, don't qualify yet to copy image of Jupyter notebook]

4 columns: number,street,town,even

desired outcome for column 'number':
1231
1233
1235
1237
1239
1238
1236
1234
1232
1230

Comment: If I understand this correctly , you first have to `groupby` street.  *Then* you partition odd/even, sort each list, and concatenate the results as needed.  As a final output, do you sort your entire data base into that new order?  Please give a sample input and desired output with two or three streets and perhaps four houses on each street.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`numpy.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html), you can define a sequence of series by which to sort. Data from @smj.

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

number_list = list(range(1, 11))

df = pd.DataFrame({'town': sorted(['Springfield', 'Shelbyville'] * 10),
                   'street': sorted(['Evergreen Terrace', 'Main Street'] * 10),
                   'number': number_list + number_list})
```

**Solution**

Be careful with ordering. `np.lexsort` works from the last element of the sequence back; e.g. `s1` has the highest priority for sorting, `s4` the lowest.

```
s1 = df['town']
s2 = df['street']
s3 = ~df['number']%2                            # i.e. "is odd"
s4 = np.where(s3, -df['number'], df['number'])  # i.e. "negate if odd"

res = df.iloc[np.lexsort((s4, s3, s2, s1))]
```

**Result**

```
print(res)

           town             street  number
0   Shelbyville  Evergreen Terrace       1
2   Shelbyville  Evergreen Terrace       3
4   Shelbyville  Evergreen Terrace       5
6   Shelbyville  Evergreen Terrace       7
8   Shelbyville  Evergreen Terrace       9
9   Shelbyville  Evergreen Terrace      10
7   Shelbyville  Evergreen Terrace       8
5   Shelbyville  Evergreen Terrace       6
3   Shelbyville  Evergreen Terrace       4
1   Shelbyville  Evergreen Terrace       2
10  Springfield        Main Street       1
12  Springfield        Main Street       3
14  Springfield        Main Street       5
16  Springfield        Main Street       7
18  Springfield        Main Street       9
19  Springfield        Main Street      10
17  Springfield        Main Street       8
15  Springfield        Main Street       6
13  Springfield        Main Street       4
11  Springfield        Main Street       2
```

Comment: tried both smj & jpp both answer my question, can't pandasice piRSquared, ran %%timeit on Jupyter NB on both - 

option smj
16.7 s ± 227 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

option jpp
1.24 s ± 2.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

-many thank, all 98k addresses sorted!

Comment: Good answer, I had to leave mid answer (-:

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt if I understand you correctly, I'm sure this can be done in a lambda function but it helped to set out the logic in a verbose way :)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

number_list = list(range(1, 11))

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'town': sorted(['Springfield', 'Shelbyville'] * 10),
        'street': sorted(['Evergreen Terrace', 'Main Street'] * 10),
        'number': number_list + number_list
    }
)

data['is_even'] = data['number'] % 2 == 0

final = pd.DataFrame()

for key, data_group in data.groupby(['town', 'street', 'is_even']):
    if key[2] == True:
        final = final.append(data_group.sort_values('number', ascending = False))
    else:
        final = final.append(data_group.sort_values('number'))

final.drop('is_even', axis = 1, inplace = True)

final
```

Gives:

[image]